# Why no StageVideo on desktop?

Tags: actionscript-3, air

**Air version:** 3.1.0.4880

**Descriptor XML contains:**

```
<renderMode>direct</renderMode>
```

(in default place, within initialWindow block)

**Compiler arguments:** -locale en_US -swf-version=13

**Video Card:** nVidia GTX 560

Tried both in debugger and standalone with captive runtime. Nadda. (also tried installing via AIR which seams to use 3.3, still nothing)

**Detection code is:**

```
public function MainClass()
    addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);
}

private function onAddedToStage(evt:Event) {
    stage.addEventListener(StageVideoAvailabilityEvent.STAGE_VIDEO_AVAILABILITY, onStageVideoReady);
    removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);
}

private function onStageVideoReady(evt:StageVideoAvailabilityEvent) :void{
    trace(evt.availability); //<-- outputs "unavailable"
}
```

Any idea what I'm missing?!

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do w/ Flex; so I'm going to remove that tag...

Comment: And; I decided to vote to close this as it is not a programming question, but rather relates to the development roadmap of a commercial software platform.

Comment: The above can be written and compiled in flex or flash, so I think flex is an accurate tag... but no biggie

Comment: For the sake of StackOverflow purity- I'd agree with you to close it. But for the sake of helpfulness to other people stuck on this problem, I'd say it's worth keeping, since others like myself may honestly think it's a programming problem and phrase the question as such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best place to find info about Adobe's public plans for the AIR Platform is to check out the [Flash Platform RoadMap](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplatform/whitepapers/roadmap.html).

this may answer your question:

> Adobe plans to add support for hardware-accelerated StageVideo in
>   Adobe AIR in a release during 2013.

Answer (score 3):

Adobe has released 3.8 version with StageVideo enabled for the desktop version (hooray!). I've tested it successfully and CPU does not exceed 5% with 1080p/h264 videos!

But not working in all systems... Not sure of the requirements but seems to depend exclusively on the graphics card.

- Win 7 / Intel Graphics Media Accelerator 3150 > Failed
- Win 7 / Nvidia ION > Ok
- Win 7 / Intel HD Graphics > Ok
- Win XP / Intel 82945G Express Chipset Family > Failed